# Index on Update Column

Tags: sql, indexing

I have the below code .. If i create an index on the update column, 
Is the query is going to be faster ?

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX tmp ON #TestTable (  
  jobid,   
  RecordGroup,
  RecordSubGroup,
  OpenDate   
) 

UPDATE #TestTable   
   SET OpenDate = OB.col1  
     , OpenWrap = OB.col2  
     , OpenBalance = OB.col3  
  FROM #TestTable ST  
  JOIN JobRecordOut OB ON OB.JobId = ST.JobId  
                      AND OB.RecordGroup = ST.RecordGroup  
                      AND OB.RecordSubGroup = ST.RecordSubGroup  
                      AND OB.RecordType = 'OB'  

DROP INDEX tmp ON #TestTable
```

Comment: No. Indexes do not make update/insert operations faster. You don't seem to know what indexes actually are, or what they do, so you should probably read a little about them before trying to apply them. Wrapping a single query in create/drop index clauses is going to be a *particularly* bad idea. Creating an index isn't free, it can actually be extremely expensive, much more so than the update itself.

Comment: Thank you for comments... yes I am very new to indexes ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends™.

Indexes only work to speed up finding records, assuming the optimizer determines an index will help.  Having an index doesn't ensure that it will be used.  No database, nevermind version, was specified when this was written to be able to provide more specific information.

Indexes slow down insert/update operations, when the index relates to a value being added/changed.  This is why indexes need to be maintained - they can get fragmented so they require "defraging" if not entire rebuilding.  Sometimes it is more cost effective to recreate the index entirely -- it depends on the data and how much of the data there is.

You have to try & test for yourself when it comes to indexes.  There is no "silver bullet"/magical answer for them.